# User.Identity.IsAuthenticated true after logout asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i have a function having a loop which sleeps for 6 second at the end of each loop

`Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(6));` 
this loops 10 times ie the function runs for 60 seconds, each time takin a pause for 6 seconds.

i have authentication test at starting of loop

```
 if (!HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    return null;
                }
```

so each time it firsts authenticate then run and wait for 6 seconds.

This is my function:

```
while (counter < 10)

            {
                if (!HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    return null;
                }

                // doing stuff

                Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(6));
                counter++;
            }
```

now the user logs out in meantime (say in 15th second) .  i use ajax to logout and hence dont want to redirect my page. even after logout IsAuthenticated is always true for all 10 loops and is false only when this function is re-executed

for logout i use:

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
Session.Abandon();
Response.Cookies.Remove(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName);
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-1));
HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
                if (cookie != null)
                {
                    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
                    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
                }
```

but still its true..
**i want to stop execution of my thread as soon as user logs out**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happened because the `IsAuthenticated` have an internal cache because is too much time-expensive to make this authentication again and again. So inside your loop and with out leaving the page, the `IsAuthenticated` is not change.

From the other hand, what is the meaning of this ? in a loop a user can see the first 4 thinks, and then can not see the rest because is no more authenticated ? No sense.

What you can do how ever is to check some other parameter if you like to check if the user have been leave and left the page.

This is the code that show this internal cache.

```
public virtual bool IsAuthenticated
{
    get
    {
        if (this.m_isAuthenticated == -1)
        {
            WindowsPrincipal principal = new WindowsPrincipal(this);
            SecurityIdentifier sid = new SecurityIdentifier(IdentifierAuthority.NTAuthority, new int[] { 11 });
            this.m_isAuthenticated = principal.IsInRole(sid) ? 1 : 0;
        }
        return (this.m_isAuthenticated == 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: actually its a long polling function which gets all notifications of a user, now since function runs for a minute and user logs out in between it should not complete the request .user never leaves the page it just logs out. and what are the other parameters that i can check

Comment: @deepakgates Maybe a value on a cookie can signal the logout and direct stop it. Maybe a value to a table to a database, and this line is connected with the user login-cookie. Its up to you, something fast.

Comment: is it possible to stop an ongoing thread from outside the function

Comment: or maybe force IsAuthenticated to not use internal cache

Comment: @deepakgates To stop a thread is better to change a flag in the thread and base on that flag to stop the loop. To force IsAuthentcated to not use the internal cache is impossible.

Comment: is it okay if i use session variables

Comment: @deepakgates Session is not change also until the loop ends. Also session will lock the other page. Not good idea.